# Unable to install Jetty9 as a service in Ubuntu

Tags: java, jetty, systemd, jetty-9

I've followed the [docs](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/startup-unix-service.html) in order to install Jetty9 as a service but whenever I run

```
service jetty start
```

It would fail with no messages, my `JETTY_HOME` is `/opt/jetty9`, contains the [home distribution](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-home/9.4.14.v20181114/) for version 9.4.14. I've also created my `JETTY_BASE` at `/usr/share/jetty9` with my webapp and modules.

Both Jetty Home and Base are owned by the user **jetty**. I've then symlinked to my init.d folder as:

```
ln -s /opt/jetty9/bin/jetty.sh /etc/init.d/jetty
```

Then I created a `/etc/default/jetty` file with the following content:

```
# change to 1 to prevent Jetty from starting
NO_START=0

# change to 'no' or uncomment to use the default setting in /etc/default/rcS
VERBOSE=yes

# Run Jetty as this user ID (default: jetty)
# Set this to an empty string to prevent Jetty from starting automatically
JETTY_USER=jetty

# The home directory of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). You need at least
# Java 6. If JAVA_HOME is not set, some common directories for OpenJDK and
# the Oracle JDK are tried.
#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

# Extra options to pass to the JVM
#JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx256m -Djava.awt.headless=true"

# Timeout in seconds for the shutdown of all webapps
#JETTY_SHUTDOWN=30

# Additional arguments to pass to Jetty
#JETTY_ARGS=

# Jetty uses a directory to store temporary files like unpacked webapps
TMPDIR=/opt/jetty9/tmp
JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty9
JETTY_BASE=/usr/share/jetty9

# Default for number of days to keep old log files in /var/log/jetty9/
#LOGFILE_DAYS=14

# If you run Jetty on port numbers that are all higher than 1023, then you # do not need authbind. It is used for binding Jetty to lower port numbers.
# (yes/no, default: no)
#AUTHBIND=yes
JETTY_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

If I start Jetty using `java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar` in my base folder it would work with no problem. Also, if I run

```
service jetty supervise
```

It would also run with no issues, but when I call `start` it fails with:

```
root@app:/usr/share/jetty9# service jetty start
Job for jetty.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status jetty.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@app:/usr/share/jetty9# service jetty status
● jetty.service - LSB: Jetty start script.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jetty; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-12-03 15:05:26 UTC; 14s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 21162 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/jetty stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21202 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jetty start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 03 15:05:22 app systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Jetty start script..
Dec 03 15:05:22 app systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Jetty start script....
Dec 03 15:05:26 app jetty[21202]: Starting Jetty: FAILED Mon Dec  3 15:05:26 UTC 2018
Dec 03 15:05:26 app systemd[1]: jetty.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 03 15:05:26 app systemd[1]: jetty.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 03 15:05:26 app systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Jetty start script..
```

This is the output of `service jetty check`:

```
root@app:/usr/share/jetty9# service jetty check
Jetty NOT running

JAVA                  =  /usr/bin/java
JAVA_OPTIONS          =  -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty9 -Djetty.base=/usr/share/jetty9 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/jetty9/tmp
JETTY_HOME            =  /opt/jetty9
JETTY_BASE            =  /usr/share/jetty9
START_D               =  /usr/share/jetty9/start.d
START_INI             =  /usr/share/jetty9/start.ini
JETTY_START           =  /opt/jetty9/start.jar
JETTY_CONF            =  /opt/jetty9/etc/jetty.conf
JETTY_ARGS            =  jetty.state=/usr/share/jetty9/jetty.state jetty-started.xml
JETTY_RUN             =  /var/run/jetty
JETTY_PID             =  /var/run/jetty/jetty.pid
JETTY_START_LOG       =  /var/run/jetty/jetty-start.log
JETTY_STATE           =  /usr/share/jetty9/jetty.state
JETTY_START_TIMEOUT   =  60
RUN_CMD               =  /usr/bin/java -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty9 -Djetty.base=/usr/share/jetty9 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/jetty9/tmp -jar /opt/jetty9/start.jar jetty.state=/usr/share/jetty9/jetty.state jetty-started.xml
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Changing the user in `/etc/default/jetty` to **root** would solve the issue, but this is not a solution, isn't it?

```
# Run Jetty as this user ID (default: jetty)
# Set this to an empty string to prevent Jetty from starting automatically
JETTY_USER=root
```

Comment: Are there any logs in `/var/run/jetty/jetty-start.log` or `/usr/share/jetty9/logs` that tell us more about what happened?

Comment: `/var/run/jetty/` only contains `jetty.pid` file and `/usr/share/jetty9/logs` remains empty unless I start it using `java -jar start.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working, the **jetty** user should have permissions to the following folders and `/usr/sbin/nologin` as shell as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49603571/264028).

```
JETTY_HOME
JETTY_BASE
/var/run/jetty   <-- couldn't find a reference to this folder in the docs
```

And add the following to your `/etc/default/jetty`:

```
JETTY_SHELL=/bin/sh
JETTY_LOGS=/usr/share/jetty9/logs
JETTY_START_LOG=/usr/share/jetty9/logs/jetty-start-log.log
```

Also you should double check that there are no remaining log files owned by other user than **jetty** in your folders.